# How to perform lookup in R using a list of unique references

Tags: r, lookup

I have two data sets. The first shows sales of unique insurance policy numbers and the destination each policy is covering. The second is a list of all the policies present in the first list which have had a claim made against them - but this second data set does not include the destination data which was present in the first data set.

How do I perform a 'lookup' type function using the unique policy numbers to find the destination for each policy in the second data set?

I have made something to work with below:

```
Policy_number <- c("AB-1", "AB-2", "AB-3", "AB-4", "AB-5", "AC-1", "AC-2", "AC-3", "AC-4", "AC-5")
Policy_destination <- c("France", "Germany", "USA", "France", "France", "Belgium", "USA", "Ireland", "Russia", "Russia")
Sale_matrix <- as.data.frame(cbind(Policy_number, Policy_destination))
Claim_number <- c("AB-2", "AC-1", "AB-4", "AC-5")
Claim_destination <- 0
Claim_matrix <- as.data.frame(cbind(Claim_number, Claim_destination))
```

I need to fill the "Claim_destination" column in the Claim_matrix with the correct destination for each policy.

Comment: Use `match`, like `Policy_destination[match(Claim_number, Policy_number)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> Claim_destination <- Policy_destination[match(Claim_number, Policy_number)]

> Claim_matrix

  Claim_number Claim_destination
1         AB-2           Germany
2         AC-1           Belgium
3         AB-4            France
4         AC-5            Russia
```